# Proof with Segments

Tags: geometry

I have an assignment (from a tutor) that tells me:
Give an informal proof for "If A-B-C and point P is on segment AC, then P is on segment AB or P is on segment BC"

To start my proof, I have assumed that A-B-C & P is on AC. Then I went on to use proof by contradiction, so I assumed that P did not lie on AB or BC.

This is where I got stuck. I am pretty sure I have to use axioms of betweenness and that points A, B, C and P are co-linear, but I am not sure how to apply these facts to prove that P lies on AB or BC.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Michael Silva

Comment: What's the definition of $A-B-C$?

Comment: @LokiClock Given three collinear points, $B$ is between $A$ and $C$ (notation $A-B-C$) if $d(A,B)+d(B,C)=d(A,C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is on $AC$, then $A-P-C$. The axioms should then state that if $X, Y, Z$ are collinear then exactly one of the following holds: $X-Y-Z,$ $X-Z-Y,$ $Y-X-Z$.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to solve it from here :)